# Can I use K-Means to group customers based on a single variable?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, python, k-means

I have a test dataset of 11m records. The dataset contains a global customer id and spend figure.

I need to group customers into the following categories:

- 0  Low
- 1 Low/Med
- 2  Med
- 3 Med/High
- 4 High

I tried K-Means to group. See results below.

As you can see 10m records or so are in the low group as 80% of the db has low to negative spend.

If I want to further segment that low group, should I just increase the number of clusters? Or is there a better algorithm given the distribution of the data?

Thanks

|  | count | mean | std | min | 25% | 50% | 75% | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cluster |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 0 | 10498822.0 | 21.147982 | 30.447597 | -22885.364 | 6.78600 | 11.4520 | 26.30600 | 160.854 |
| 1 | 714573.0 | 300.654938 | 115.836596 | 160.855 | 207.94600 | 269.0280 | 366.02400 | 651.081 |
| 2 | 57318.0 | 1002.263623 | 400.515911 | 651.084 | 723.53375 | 841.8320 | 1118.37575 | 2370.803 |
| 3 | 14415.0 | 3739.988910 | 924.921881 | 2371.056 | 2993.61250 | 3599.1800 | 4319.69000 | 6162.907 |
| 4 | 3010.0 | 8584.038995 | 2476.616904 | 6163.451 | 6905.48800 | 7861.5815 | 9318.03100 | 22884.357 |

Comment: You could well also pre-specify intervals of values for your classes in a non-data driven way, or choose the classes so that they all have the same size. Why do you think k-means is better than this? In fact the terms "low", "low/med" etc. seem to refer to the interpretation of the observed values, and k-means is not interested in this interpretation, so why do you think k-means will come up with clusters that behave well according to your pre-specified description?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue is that the values could change over a period of time and there are 30+ columns I need to do this for so pre-defining will be an issue. I was hoping there was a programmatic way to group in low/low-med etc.

Comment: This depends on what you really need. k-means is defined by an objective function that may or may not deliver what you want. I suspect that out of the purely data driven clustering methods it may well be the best here, but you may want to involve side conditions that make sure it gives you something that works even better for you. But then you need to specify what's wrong with the k-means solution and what you need instead. As said already, if you want the same number of observations in each category, you can enforce this directly rather than doing k-means.

Answer (score 1):

Given your description, I would just assign cutoff points at percentiles of the distribution of total spend. With five categories, equal intervals (same number of observations in each category) would be quintiles, i.e. [0%,20%), [20%,40%),[40-60%),[60%,80%),[80%-100%].

Answer (score 0):

If you want a data driven clustering, k-means looks promising in the sense that it will produce clusters with similar within-cluster variance, which may make sense in your application. The problem of imbalanced cluster sizes may come from a very skew distribution of values, and k-means may produce something more to your liking if you transform the data first, say, by taking logs or square roots. As written in the comments, it all depends on what you really need in this situation. There is no uniquely "true" clustering that could be found reliably from data. Different clusterings are possible on the same data and background knowledge regarding the meaning of the data and aim of clustering is required to decide between them.